# Is there a way / npm command combination to scan the package dependency in the current directory and add them into package.json?

Tags: npm, dependencies, package.json

Is there a way / npm command combination to scan the package dependency in the current directory and add them into package.json?

I know,

**$npm install  --save**

**$npm install  --save-dev**

From
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json

But it is still manual, is there some intelligent way to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing automatic, but you still have a way to simplify this.

`npm ls --depth=0` gives a list of the top-level packages installed in a project directory.

On it's own, it isn't pretty, but you can dump it to a text file with something like `npm ls --depth=0 > stuff.txt` and edit that down to a "list" of package names.

From there, you can build either your `package.json` lines or use `npm i <packages> -S` to re-install and save to `package.json`.

That said, you can also dump packages to json using `npm ls --json`.  You could parse that file, open `package.json`, append the new dependencies, and save...but that sounds like more work than editing a few lines for a situation that should be relatively rare...